# Как построить цикл для перелистывания вкладок?

Tags: php

Цикл один не получается построить для перелистывания вкладок:

```
 <?php foreach($news as $new): ?>
       <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-<?=$i?>" name="tab-group-1" checked>
  <label for="tab-<?=$i?>">
    <?=$new['title']?>
    </label>
           <div class="content">
               <p><?=$new['description']?></p>
    </div> 
       </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Там, где `$i` должно быть, от 1 до 3 считать, чтобы три вкладки были.

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

`$i` у вас не назначена, если это ключ, то попробуйте так:

```
   foreach($news as $i => $new)
```

Если критично, чтобы именно от 1 до 3, то

```
   id="tab-<?=$i + 1?>"
```